# Issue to fetch Linkedin connections

Tags: php, json, api, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I tried to fetch Linkedin connections of logged in user with below API Request,

> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,firstName,lastName,email-address)?format=json

I got this error,

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Access to connections denied",
  "requestId": "OFP0JOLOHO",
  "status": 403,
  "timestamp": 1438683812562
}
```

So how can we fetch all connections using Linkedin API?

Answer (score 0):

please use this URL as your API Request

**https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,num-connections,picture-url)?format=json**

It works for me

Comment: I have tried with this API Request and it gives only total number of connections. I want to display all connection with his/her name